# Findstr based of file names in a directory

Tags: xml, batch-file, cmd

I would like to search for specific texts within multiple .xml files. I found this code online that works fine.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
 
(for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /L "<a> <b> <c>" *.xml') do (
   set "line=%%a"
   set "line=!line:*<a>=!"
   set "line=!line:*<b>=!"
   set "line=!line:*<c>=!"
   for /F "delims=<" %%b in ("!line!") do echo %%b
)) > temp.txt
```

But the code loop through *.xml files in directory randomly, not based on file name.

How can I change this code to make it search based on xml file name or date mofified?

Add sort on *.xml but doesn't work

Comment: Replace `*.xml` by filename.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on sorted filenames. NTFS automatically sorts them alphabetically, but FATx doesn't sort files. New files are just added to the table of contents. So you need another `for` loop to sort the files (`dir /on` for name sorting - see `dir /?` for more sort options) and use the existent loop to process just one of those files at a time:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

(for /F "delims=" %%f in ('dir /b /on *.xml') do (
  for /F "delims=" %%a in ('findstr /I /L "<a> <b> <c>" "%%f"') do (
    etc.
  )
)) > temp.txt
```

(untested)